# Japanese characters in file appearing garbled after changing Formats (Region & Language) in Windows English OS to Japanese (Java application)

Tags: java, windows, unicode, fonts, internationalization

Whilst investigating an internationalisation issue in some Java code whereby on a Japanese Windows 7 OS, the Japanese titles of media files (images/videos) appear as Chinese characters in excel files exported from a manager application (that records events such as item A started "playing", stopped "playing", item B started and so on), I came across a problem with displaying Japanese characters in an applet. These displayed correctly outside of the application (e.g. on my desktop). Even in the application but outside the applet I could type Japanese and it would be displayed correctly (e.g. when logging in to the application). In the applet, on the other hand, the Japanese characters were appearing as open boxes. This type of issue has been written about extensively, and I tried some of the fixes, but without success. My first, unsuccessful, attempt was to place a Japanese true type font into the jre/lib/fonts/fallback folder.

At this stage, I tested my application anyway (by exporting the excel files mentioned above) and found that the Japanese titles were correctly stored in the excel files mentioned above. However, I then tried another suggested fix for the incorrectly displaying Japanese characters in the applet. This was to set the Formats property under Region and Language (Control Panel) to Japanese. Unfortunately, the applet display problem remained as before, but in addition now the Japanese titles of the media files are appearing garbled in the excel files. An example:

â‘¡ã‚½ãƒ‹ãƒ¼æ��ä¿�ã€€è‡ªå‹•è»Šä¿�é™ºã€€ã‚¯ãƒ«ãƒžã�¨äººã�¨ã€Œæ™‚ä»£ã�Œå¤‰ã‚�ã�£ã�¦ã‚‚ã€�ç¯‡ã€€ã€�30ç§’ã€‘.jpg

when it should be:

②ソニー損保　自動車保険　クルマと人と「時代が変わっても」篇　【30秒】.jpg

I now wish to get back to the original situation. I have set the Formats back to English (United Kingdom). I have also restarted Tomcat, MySql, rebooted my machine and recompiled all my Java code. However, I am unable to get back to the happy situation of the ungarbled Japanese titles in the excel files.

Comment: Eventually managed to get back to producing Japanese characters in the excel file after forcing a locale change programmatically and several recompiles. I cannot pinpoint which of my changes exactly resulted in reversion to the correct behaviour. Sadly, the original issue with the Japanese characters appearing as Chinese in the excel file on a Japanese OS machine is still there.

Comment: Oh and the Japanese characters appearing as empty boxes was fixed by changin the locale to Japanese programmatically.

Comment: Probably what you've said as Chinese characters are actually Japanese [Kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) characters.

Comment: @eee I think it would be more accurate to say that what Japanese call "kanji" are actually Chinese characters. Even what they call "kokuji" (as well as their kana) are derived from Chinese characters.

Comment: @erickson It is well understood since I have put the link to Kanji reference to Wikipedia which states exactly as what you've said. I've said it like that just in the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now quite certain that this was solved by reverting Formats back to English, recompiling the code and restarting Tomcat. I must have missed an area of code in the recompile.